# Does my Sago Palm have root/ crown rot?

Tags: rot

I have looked for examples online and see nothing that looks like this. My leaves yellowed so I pruned them as I saw suggested but then I decided to check out my roots. I want to try to save this baby but I am lost. Is it too far gone? (I have re potted directly after taking this photo)

[image: Roots]

Comment: Looks more dried out, how often did you water it? What kind of weather did you have when the problems started? Was it hot and dry or cold and wet?

Comment: It was inside and stayed on my kitchen counter where it could get sun from the window daily. I keep my house at around 72 currently no less. It was never below 68 in the winter. I got it at lowes in the clearance discarded pile (because it had one yellow leaf) and I wanted to save it. It did well for a good while I watered based on the touch test. If it felt dry I'd give a little water or use a glass watering globe. You know those you stick in the dirt? It even started growing a new frond! Then one day I went downstairs and all the leaves were yellow

Comment: I thought maybe it was getting too much sun. Then someone said I needed to let it get some outdoor sun so I did that and now here we are. I dont want to give up but dont know where to go from here 